# Devise recovarable phone number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

i am customizing devise and have it working with two factor authentication,

now i want users to be able to reset there account by sending the token through phone number rather than emails.
here is my code for sending instruction

```
   def self.send_reset_password_instructions attributes = {}
          recoverable = find_recoverable_or_initialize_with_errors(reset_password_keys, attributes, :not_found)
          # pry.binding
          recoverable.send_reset_password_instructions
          recoverable
        end
```

below is the code use to fine user

```
def self.find_recoverable_or_initialize_with_errors required_attributes, attributes, error = :invalid
      (case_insensitive_keys || []).each {|k| attributes[k].try(:downcase!)}

      attributes = attributes.slice(*required_attributes)
      attributes.delete_if {|_key, value| value.blank?}

      if attributes.size == required_attributes.size
        if attributes.key?(:login)
          login = attributes.delete(:login)
          record = find_record(login)
        else
          record = where(attributes).first
        end
      end

      unless record
        record = new

        required_attributes.each do |key|
          value = attributes[key]
          record.send("#{key}=", value)
          record.errors.add(key, value.present? ? error : :blank)
        end
      end
      record
    end
```

when i try to do recovery, it try send instruction through email and fails

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `email' for #<User:0x007f8ba46ee100>):
```

becuase i remove email field.

i need direction to send instruction through sms

Comment: The codes you have posted looks identical to devise's source. I have not matched line by line, can you please tell me what modification have you done that ? I mean any customization ? Have you changed this line `config.reset_password_keys = [ :email ]` in devise initializer to your phone number field ?

Comment: in the above code i look the record with the username instead of the email.
in my initializer i have `config.reset_password_keys = [:login]`